# ANR in CardEditText customview and fragment loading slow

Tags: android

I have written a custom view CardEditText in library module which extends CradView with ConstraintLayout and a TextView and EditText. I reused this CardEditText across the app for example registration screen with 8 CardEditText views in ConstraintLayout. It produces ANR and fragment loading is very slow. What are the best practices I need to do to avoid ANR because of CustomView?

My Code:
https://gist.github.com/rramprasad/d4516499a04a50dcf8de8899e06923d3

Comment: any code? it's so weird when someone with so high rep.score and lot of badges don't understand that he should to show the code firstly

Comment: @Subzero https://gist.github.com/rramprasad/d4516499a04a50dcf8de8899e06923d3

Comment: Any suggestions for this code?